# SSH ignores characters after correct password string?

Tags: password, authentication, sshd

Remote machine 10.10.10.1 has password "asdFGH12" for user named "user". I'm able to log in even if I type in password "asdFGH12dasdkjlkjasdus" or any other characters after the "asdFGH12" string.

```
$ ssh -v 10.10.10.1
OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.1 [10.10.10.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_4.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.1 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.10.10.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:58
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
Last login: Tue Apr 23 14:30:59 2013 from 10.10.10.2
Have a lot of fun...
user@server:~>
```

Is this a known behavior of (certain) SSH server versions?

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: My ssh daemon ( OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 ) does **not** allow me to add extra characters after the password.

Comment: Problem is definitely with the hashing scheme. DES/traditional crypt hashing truncates or pads all given passwords to eight characters so the hashing algorithm will work. I'd wager you're using a traditional unix variant, most BSD's and Linux distros have at least been at md5 by default for the last decade or so.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not a limitation on the part of your SSH server, this is a limitation on the part of your server's password hash algorithm.

When hashing passwords on Unix, the `crypt()` function is called. This may use one of many backends, a possibility is using DES, or another limiting algorithm (for this particular case, I will assume your server is using DES). DES is generally not used by default in modern operating systems because it results in a particularly bad limitation: password strength and validation is limited to 8 bytes.

This means that if your password was set as "foobarbaz", it becomes "foobarba", usually without a warning or notice. The same limitation applies to validation, which means that "foobarbaz", "foobarba", and "foobarbazqux" all validate for this particular case.

Answer (score 20):

I suspect you're OS is using DES password encryption, which only supports a maximum of 8 characters.

https://serverfault.com/questions/361591/ssh-accepts-only-the-half-password

From `man crypt(3)`

> GNU EXTENSION
>
> The  glibc2  version  of  this  function  has the following 
>     additional features.  If salt is a character string
>     starting with the three characters "$1$" followed by at most eight
>     characters,  and  optionally  terminated  by "$",  then  instead 
>     of using the DES machine, the glibc crypt function uses an MD5-based
>     algorithm, and outputs up to 34 bytes, namely "$1$<string>$", where 
>     "<string>" stands for the up to 8 characters  following  "$1$"  in
>     the  salt, followed by 22 bytes chosen from the set [a–zA–Z0–9./].
>     The entire key is significant here (instead of only the first 8 bytes).

You can check your pam setup to see whether you're using MD5 or DES:

```
% egrep "password.*pam_unix.so" /etc/pam.d/system-auth
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
```

You can also confirm which hashing function your system is using with this command:

```
% authconfig --test | grep hashing
 password hashing algorithm is md5
```

And you can see in this systems `/etc/shadow` file that it's using MD5 as well:

```
root:$1$<DELETED PASSWORD HASH>:14245:0:99999:7:::
```

The codes you'll see in the `/etc/shadow` for each type of hashing:

- $1 – MD5
- $2 – blowfish
- $2a – eksblowfish
- $5 – SHA-256
- $6 – SHA-512

You can reconfigure your system with this command:

```
% authconfig --passalgo=sha512 --update
```

Any existing passwords will need to be regenerated, you can use this command to force users to reset them the next time they login:

```
% chage -d 0 userName
```

#### References

- https://serverfault.com/questions/361591/ssh-accepts-only-the-half-password
- https://serverfault.com/questions/129137/what-is-the-longest-password-for-ssh
- https://scottlinux.com/2011/06/25/upgrade-red-hat-centos-password-hashing/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-upgrading-password-hashing/

Comment: Checking the PAM config will only tell you what the system is using *right now*, not what was used to encrypt the password that the user is using. It is possible for them to be different if it was ever changed.

Comment: Sorry this was as hot question, I couldn't type the answer as fast as everyone was thinking 8-).

Comment: Note that `authconfig` is generally specific to RHEL (and derivatives).

Comment: if `authconfig` specific then alternate option is `grep ENCRYPT_METHOD /etc/login.defs`